# how to remove a file in Jenkins through Execute Shell

Tags: shell, files, delete, github, jenkins

this is the console output of Jenkins' build. Here, you could see that the file Oct Release SQL.txt is present in the path but when I am deleting it by using rm Oct Release SQL.txt, it is not able to find any such file or directory. Could someone please help with why is this happening?

- pwd
  /opt/data/jenkins/workspace/OBS_Github_trial
- cd /opt/data/jenkins/workspace/OBS_Github_trial
- ls
  OBS_71_01_00_WS
  Oct Release SQL.txt
  Restart OBS servers(1).txt
- rm Oct Release SQL.txt
  rm: cannot remove ‘Oct’: No such file or directory
  rm: cannot remove ‘Release’: No such file or directory
  rm: cannot remove ‘SQL.txt’: No such file or directory
  Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure

[image]

Comment: Maybe just escaping the spaces or putting the filename in quotes?

Comment: Adding double quotes to the filename worked (rm "Oct Release SQL.txt")
Thank you so much stoney! :)